# ClassNotFoundException in embedded Jetty when using Module system

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, classnotfoundexception, hk2

I use an embedded Jetty (11.0.13) server with Jersey (3.1.0) that provides a simple REST interface which returns JSON objects. The JSON objects are serialized using Jackson.

The setup works fine as long as I don´t use Java´s module system.
But when I add the `module-info.java` file (see below), I get the following error as soon as I call the service.

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jakarta.xmlbind.JakartaXmlBindAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JakartaXmlBindAnnotationIntrospector.java:137)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 83 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:429)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
    ...
```

To make it work, I have to add the JAX-B-API to the `pom.xml` and to the `module-info.java`.
The error only occurs when using Java modules. When I simply delete the `module-info.java` file, everythink works fine even without the JAX-B dependency.

This is the point where I am really confused. Why do I need the JAX-B dependency when I use the module system, but not when I don´t use it? And why does the `ClassNotFoundException` even occur? Shouldn´t warn the module system about missing dependencies on startup?

I hope someone can explain that. It took me days to make it work.

---

This is the setup that produces the issue:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
        ServletHolder servletHolder = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.example.demo");
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", "true");
        
        server.start();
    }
}
```

**DemoResource.java**

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class DemoResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public HelloDto hello() {
        return new HelloDto("Hello, World!");
    }
    
    public record HelloDto(String value) {
        @JsonGetter("value")
        public String value() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

**module-info.java**

```java
module demo {
    requires org.eclipse.jetty.server;
    requires org.eclipse.jetty.servlet;
    requires jersey.container.servlet.core;
    requires jakarta.ws.rs;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard JVM behavior of classpath (old school Java) and modulepath (new school Java Platform Module System, aka JPMS).

Once you have a `module-info.class` you have a modulepath active, and all of the access rules it has.

Your runtime can have both at the same time, and this is quite normal.

Don't rely on old school classpath to get around bad code and bad behavior, use JPMS and `module-info.class` and you'll know what the developers of those projects jars intend for you to use (you won't be allowed to use internal classes for example, as those are highly volatile and can change at a moments notice).

`jakarta.xml.bind` is required by HK2 to operate, so you have to declare it in your build dependencies to just compile, and then your `module-info.java` to be able to access it.

Check the other answers here on Stackoverflow for advice on how to use `module-info.java` properly (there's far more to it than just `requires <module>`).

Comment: So that means that the HK2 is an automatic module and the JPMS is not able to get the transitive dependencies? That´s why I have to declare it explicitely?